# PHP variable is not populating into HTML datetime-local field on form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to populate a HTML datetime-local field with a PHP $_POST variable. When I do an echo of the variable, the data displays correctly but it is not populating into the datetime-local input field. I'm sure it's a syntax error but cannot see the problem. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<label>Arrived on site date<input type="datetime-local" name="arriveDate" id="arriveDate" value="<?php echo $arriveDate; ?>"></label>
```

PHP: this code doesn't give me an error but does not fill the field

```
$arriveDate = $_POST['arriveDate'];
echo $arriveDate = date("c", strtotime($arriveDate));
```

I have also tried the following which didn't work:

- this gave me an error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

```
$arriveDate = $_POST['arriveDate'];
$arriveDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP',$arriveDate);
```

- this did not give me an error but did not fill the field either

```
$arriveDate = $_POST['arriveDate'];
$arriveDate = strtotime($arriveDate);
```

when I echo `$_POST['arriveDate'];` I get the format 2019-01-31T19:30
I am hoping this is just some silly syntax issue. Please let me know what you think. Thanks

Comment: Did you debug your variables? What values are you passing in and receiving?

Comment: Try the following format: `Y-m-d\TH:i`

Comment: Yes ```echo $arriveDate = date("c", strtotime($arriveDate));``` gives me 2019-01-31T19:30:00+01:00

Comment: I tried `$arriveDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i',$arriveDate);` and I get the error Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: You need to pass string into `strtotime` and then the result will go into `date()`

Comment: okay maybe I'm looking at this wrong. If I am getting the $_POST from the form as a datetime-local value, what is variable type? I thought it was sent as a string.

Comment: I could be making this question too convoluted...basically what do I have to do to get the form to populate with the $_POST variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal but these date formats are kind of complicated. As you said you were getting

```
 2019-01-31T19:30:00+01:00
```

from the echo, without the timezone value it will autofill the input properly. You can just remove the timezone.

```
 $arriveDate = date("c", strtotime($arriveDate));
 list($Date)=explode('+', $arriveDate);
 $arriveDate = $Date;
 <input type="datetime-local" name="arriveDate" id="arriveDate" value="<?= $arriveDate ?>">
```

Comment: Okay this worked! thank you:). When you say it's not ideal...what are the issues?

Comment: also, I would like to keep the $arriveDate variable instead of $Date. `list($arriveDate)=explode('+', $arriveDate);` is not working. Any suggestions on the proper way to go about this?

Comment: No issues, just kinda ugly I suppose, just switch the variable names either before or after, can't post code as I'm on mobile

Comment: sorry - I'm stumped. I did the following: 
`list($Date)=explode('+', $arriveDate); 
echo $arriveDate = $Date; Arrived on site date<input type="datetime-local" name="arriveDate" id="arriveDate" value="<?php echo $arriveDate; ?>">`

The echo is giving me the correct value (2019-01-01T19:30:00) but the input field is not getting populated. It only seems to work if I use the exact code you gave.

Comment: Are you sure your code is as you commented? Seems correct to me. I edited again with what should work, which is pretty much what you wrote, although I can't test it right now for you, we already did the hard part, remapping the variable shouldn't be much trouble

Comment: Yes I agree...putting one variable into another is very simple so there must be something else going on. So I did an echo right before the input and the variable $arriveDate had the correct value in it. I'm thinking there is something wrong with the input. I switched it to type="text" and it shows the value just fine. Any thoughts on why the input would show the value for $Date and not $arriveDate when it is a datetime-local?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine, we can also try and set $Date date("c" ...)); And then list($arriveDate)=explode('+', $Date); and not need to remap it later, I'm on mobile again

Comment: So frustrating...this is what I am trying: `Arrived on site date<input type="text" name="arriveDate" id="arriveDate" value="<?php echo $arriveDate; ?>">
  <input type="datetime-local" name="arriveDate" id="arriveDate" value="<?php echo $arriveDate; ?>">` and my results are the first input field shows the proper value and the second shows nothing. I've tried your suggestion above and I get the same result.

Comment: I've changed the datetime-local field to datetime and I get the correct results. Very odd...maybe there a bug there. I am going with that solution for now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Very well, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) (if supported at all) accepts the value in the form of **yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm**
This is not the ISO-8601 format, so `date('c')` will not work. Try something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$arriveDate = $_POST['arriveDate'];
$arriveDate = date("Y-m-d\TH:i", strtotime($arriveDate));
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="datetime-local" name="arriveDate" value="<?=$arriveDate; ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will match the format of HTML input, without timezone or seconds part. e.g. `2019-01-31T19:18`

Comment: Okay I've tried:
 `echo $arriveDate = $_POST['arriveDate'];
echo "<br>";
echo $arriveDate = date("Y-m-d\TH:i", strtotime($arriveDate));`
I'm getting :
2019-01-31T19:30 and 
2019-01-31T19:30
But the field is not getting filled out

Comment: Then you need to show us more of your code, something else is probably at play. My example above works.

Comment: Okay, so Joao Nunes's solution worked below. But I really think your answer should work as well. I'm not sure what other parts of the code to show you.